# PayPal dummy accounts

Tags: wordpress, paypal

This is completely new territory for me.  I'm in the process of getting up to speed with WordPress with the aim of using it as a resource to raise funds for charities.  I've been looking at links such as:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

and

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-can-my-charity-or-nonprofit-use-PayPal-to-collect-donations-FAQ1068

together with a number of other resources, but I need to know exactly where to start from scratch.

Basically I would like to set up a test PayPal account which can accept dummy credit card numbers for both dummy deposits and withdrawals in order to test it out in such a way that from a WordPress theme I can make mock donations, then check that the "balance" has been credited, then be a dummy charity that can make mock withdrawals.

Presumably there are free test accounts that can do this with documentation.  I've looked at some of the documentation, but it would be nice to know where to start, as there is so much.

Looking forward to some friendly and helpful reply.

Christopher Sharp

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question simply, use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com.

If you want to manage all your sandbox accounts, you will need to create the accounts within PayPal Developer.

1. Visit [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com) and sign up for a PayPal account or login to an existing one.

To access PayPal Developer site, you need to login with a real PayPal account (non-sandbox).

2. [Create a sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/create) after logging into PayPal Developer.

You will be creating a testing account you will use when logging into the testing environment.

3. After creating all the accounts you need, ie. receiving side (you) & sending side (donator), you can use these accounts to make sandbox transactions.

Basically, production is www.paypal.com and sandbox (testing) is www.sandbox.paypal.com.

As with PayPal integration with WordPress, there should be a lot of plugins for this. You can even just generate a HTML donate button from within your PayPal account to create a donate button that will send donation to that account which generated the button.